# How to get file names, replace - with a space and insert in a file with shell/bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm creating Svelte component files for SVG icons.

I have many SVG files in a dir:

```
ab-testing.svg
abacus.svg
abjad-arabic.svg
abjad-hebrew.svg
abugida-devanagari.svg
abugida-thai.svg
access-point-check.svg
access-point-minus.svg
...
```

In each file, I'd like to insert strings.

For example using a file `access-point-minus.svg`:

It has the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  version="1.1" 
  id="mdi-access-point-minus" 
  width="24" 
  height="24" 
  viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<path d="M16 12C16 # removed for brevity ........" /></svg>
```

And I'd like to change the content to the following:

```
<script>
    export let size = '24';
    export let color = 'currentColor';
    export let ariaLabel = 'access point minus'
</script>
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    version="1.1" 
    id="mdi-access-point-minus" 
    aria-label={ariaLabel}
    width={size}
    height={size}
    fill={color}
    class={$$props.class}
    {...$$props}
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    ><path # removed for brevity ...
</svg>
```

And change the file name from `access-point-minus.svg` to `AccessPointMinus.svelte`.

I'd like to repeat the same things to all files in a directory.

Comment: if files have no "funny char" (e.g. newline or so), you can generate for each file a variable `filetext=$(basename "$file" .svg| tr '-' ' ')`

Comment: on a  side note, in you first `sed -i` rather than escape multiple `/` change separator e.g. `sed -i 's;svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN";;'` (provided `;` is not used in search string)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show example fine names that shall be renamed with the expected new name and explain what should be inserted in the `ariaLabel` line in this case. To get the file name you can process the files in a `for` loop instead of using a wildcard argument for `sed`. Instead of separate `sed` commands you can use one `sed` with several commands, e.g. `sed -e 's/foo/bar/' -e 's#baz#quux#' ...`.

Comment: I just update it again.